# Javascript scroll with buttons; Can be repeated as often as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some movies I want to display on my website within a horizontal, scrollable div.
Because I removed the scrollbar, the user can not scroll anymore, which is why I added two buttons. One button to move right and one button to move left.

The problem is, the buttons can be pressed as often as desired. So the movies won't get displayed anymore, because of the through Javascript added margin.

How can I resolve this issue?
I want to disable the left-button, when the start is reached and I want to disable the right-button, when the end is reached.

```js
$('#right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.movie-scroll').animate({
    marginLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "fast");
});
$('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.movie-scroll').animate({
    marginLeft: "+=200px"
   }, "fast");
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}

.sc_content {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title_home {
 font-size: 18px;
 margin: 30px 0px -10px 30px;
}

.movie-scroll {
 height: 300px;
 white-space: nowrap; 
 overflow-x: scroll;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.thumbnail-movie-box {
 width: 130px;
 margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.thumbnail-movie-content {
 display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-movie-poster {
 width: 130px;
 height: 195px;
}

.thumbnail-movie-title {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
 margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.thumbnail-movie-year {
 font-size: 12px;
 margin: -5px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<div class="sc_content">
  <h1 class="title_home">Movies</h1>
  <a href="#" id="left-button">Left</a>
  <div class="movie-scroll">
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
   <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
   </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="right-button">Right</a>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qynpgj22/1/

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zbavtpj4/

Change your javascript to the following:

```
var index = 0;

$('#right-button').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
    if(index <= 7){
      $('.movie-scroll').animate({
          marginLeft: "-=200px"
      }, "fast");
      index++;
    }
});
$('#left-button').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
    if(index >= -2){
      $('.movie-scroll').animate({
          marginLeft: "+=200px"
       }, "fast");
       index--;
     }
});
```

Uses an index to track position and doesn't change the margin if the index isn't in range. Boundaries are manually defined in this example. It is possible define the boundaries programmatically, but I don't have the time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Before animating, you should check .movie-scroll current margin-left.

If it's >= 0, the #left-button action shouldn't happen.

If it's bigger than .movie-scroll width, the #right-button action shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about width calculation and comparison.

Here is your [**updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/bcLsqugx/).

```
console.clear();

var movieWidth = $('.movie-scroll').outerWidth();
console.log(movieWidth);
var viewportWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
console.log(viewportWidth);
var moviePosterWidth = $(".thumbnail-movie-poster").outerWidth();
console.log(moviePosterWidth);

var leftBoundReached = false;
var rightBoundReached = false;

$('#right-button').click(function() {

  event.preventDefault();
  if(!rightBoundReached){
    $('.movie-scroll').animate({
      marginLeft: "-=200px"
    }, "fast");
  }
  checkScrolling("right");
});

$('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(!leftBoundReached){
    $('.movie-scroll').animate({
      marginLeft: "+=200px"
    }, "fast");
  }

  checkScrolling("left");
});

function checkScrolling(direction){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var scrolled = parseInt($('.movie-scroll').css("marginLeft"));
    console.log(scrolled);

    leftBoundReached = false;
    rightBoundReached = false;

    if(scrolled>viewportWidth-2*moviePosterWidth && direction=="left"){
      console.log("left "+scrolled);
      leftBoundReached = true;
    }
    if(-scrolled>=viewportWidth+movieWidth+0.10*moviePosterWidth && direction=="right"){
      console.log("right "+scrolled);
      rightBoundReached = true;
    }
  },300);
}
```

I left a lot console logs for you to get what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

I might be super late in posting my answer, but this solution is scalable and hope works as you wish.

```js
/* JS */
var scrollWidth = parseInt($('.movie-scroll .thumbnail-movie-box').first().next().position().left) - parseInt($('.movie-scroll .thumbnail-movie-box').first().position().left);
var noOfItems = $('.movie-scroll .thumbnail-movie-box').length;
var count = 0;
$('#right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var movieScroll = $('.movie-scroll');
  movieScroll.filter(function() {
    if (count == (noOfItems - 1))
      return false;
    count++;
    return true;
  }).animate({
    marginLeft: "-=" + scrollWidth + "px"
  }, "fast");
});
$('#left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var movieScroll = $('.movie-scroll');
  movieScroll.filter(function() {
    if (count == 0)
      return false;
    count--;
    return true;
  }).animate({
    marginLeft: "+=" + scrollWidth + "px"
  }, "fast");
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sc_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title_home {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 30px 0px -10px 30px;
}

.movie-scroll {
  height: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.thumbnail-movie-box {
  width: 130px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumbnail-movie-content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-movie-poster {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
}

.thumbnail-movie-title {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.thumbnail-movie-year {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: -5px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sc_content">
  <h1 class="title_home">Movies</h1>
  <a href="#" id="left-button">Left</a>
  <div class="movie-scroll">
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-movie-box">
      <a href="">
        <div class="thumbnail-movie-content">
          <img class="thumbnail-movie-poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ijoPd2gdt8jW982fGemySKDOGtv.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <p class="thumbnail-movie-title">Split</p>
      </a>
      <p class="thumbnail-movie-year">2016</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="right-button">Right</a>
```